# Returning maxima of multiple sets

Tags: list-manipulation, combinatorics

I am trying to prove a conjecture which involves the SetParitions[n] function (which requires the Combinatorica package). This function returns a list of all the set partitions of n. I'd like to take the max from each "block" in each set partition, add n+1, and then multiple the results together.

For example, if `n=3`, we have

```
SetPartitions[3]={{{1,2,3}},{{1},{2,3}},{{1,2},{3}},{{1,3},{2}},{{1},{2},{3}}}
```

The first set partition is `{1,2,3}` and only has one block. So its max is 3 and I would like to return `(3+4)=7`. The next partition is `{1}{2,3}`, so the two max values are 1 and 3. This should return `(1+4)*(3+4)=5*7=35`. The following parition is `{1,2}{3}`, which has max values 2 and 3, yielding `(2+4)*(3+4)=6*7=42`.

I really appreciate any assistance.

Edit: I also need the size of each block. For example, if I use `{1,2}{3}`, I need to use the fact that the block `{1,2}` is of size 2 and the block `{3}` is of size 1.

Comment: Does `Times @@@ (Map[Max, SetPartitions[n], {2}] + n + 1)` do what you want?

Comment: Yes! Thank you!

Comment: With respect to the edit, try `Map[Length, SetPartitions[n], {2}]`. If these suit your needs, you can write an answer to your own question.

Answer (score 5):

I needed the following two functions:

```
Times @@@ (Map[Max, SetPartitions[n], {2}] + n + 1)

Map[Length, SetPartitions[n], {2}]
```